# C4.5 How to select the split point (threshold) for a Continuous Attribute

Tags: cart, threshold

Using the "play golf" or "play ball" data (listed at the bottom), to pick the root node we look at Outlook, Temperature, Humidity, and Wind, to see which has the highest GainRatio.

Now, Outlook will be chosen as the attribute with the highest GainRatio. However, I am confused that Humidity (a Continuous Attribute) selects the split point **80** having a **GainRatio=0.1087**, while **65** has a higher **GainRatio=0.1285**. The split point 80 does have a higher Gain, but not GainRatio.

I have seen literature say roughly "*pick the split point for a continuous attribute to be the one giving the most gain*"... this seems counterintuitive to me that the split point is based on Gain alone, opposed to when comparing all the attributes you select the highest GainRatio to be the next decision node.

I hope to gain some clarity here.

Thanks.

EDIT:
The crux of the question is: what is the appropriate method for selecting the threshold split point of a continuous attribute? Is it (1) the Gain or (2) the Gain Ratio?

The calculations are as follows:

OUTLOOK:
Gain = 0.2467
SplitInfo = 1.5774
Gain Ratio = 0.1564

TEMPERATURE:
Gain = 0.0292
SplitInfo = 1.5566
Gain Ratio = 0.0187

HUMIDITY:
Possible split points = { 65, 70, 75, 78, 80, 85, 90, 95, 96 }

Split 65:
Gain = 0.0477
SplitInfo = 0.3712
Gain Ratio = 0.1285

Split 80:
Gain = 0.1022
SplitInfo = 0.9402
Gain Ratio = 0.1087

WIND:
Gain = 0.0481
SplitInfo = 0.9852
Gain Ratio = 0.0488

DATA:
Outlook Temperature Humidity Wind Play
sun hot     85      low no
sun     hot     90      high    no
overcast    hot     78      low yes
rain        sweet       96      low yes
rain        cold        80      low yes
rain        cold        70      high    no
overcast    cold        65      high    yes
sun     sweet       95      low no
sun     cold        70      low yes
rain        sweet       80      low yes
sun     sweet       70      high    yes
overcast    sweet       90      high    yes
overcast    hot     75      low yes
rain        sweet       80      high    no

- sorry, could not format data nicely

Answer (score 0):

More sophisticated capabilities for handling continuous attributes are covered by Quinlan.  We run into a conundrum here because the **gain ratio** will also be influenced by the actual threshold used by the continuous-valued attribute.

In particular, if the threshold apportions the instances nearly equally, then the gain ratio is minimal (since the entropy of the variable falls in the denominator). Therefore, Quinlan advocates going back to the regular information gain for choosing a threshold but continuing the use of the gain ratio for choosing the attribute in the first place.

Comment: Might be of service to include a reference for Quinlan.

Comment: What is quinlan?

Comment: It is not appropriate to split a continuous predictor unless you can demonstrate a discontinuity in the relationship between that predictor and outcome.

Comment: Ross Quinlan is the name of a person who developed C4.5 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm